# Testing form submissions that do not submit anywhere with sinon, mocha, and chai

Tags: forms, coffeescript, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I have a simple form that does not submit anywhere (using `preventDefault`) but updates the UI instead. I want to test that the UI is updated appropriately after the form is submitted both with an error and without, but the `submit` does not run in my test suite.

The suite is setup using `jsdom`, `mocha`, and `sinon`. An example follows. My question is, is it possible to test do a manual form submission (handled through jQuery) in jsdom/with sinon where the action is `""` and there is an `onsubmit` callback?

There is a simple form submit handler in my class file.

```
# MyClass.coffee
$('#my-form').on 'submit', (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  @doSomeStuff()
```

My test case injects content into the a form field and calls submit. Imagine that in the suite there is an instance of MyClass

```
# MyClass_spec.coffee
it 'can submit a form', ->
  myClass = new MyClass()
  doSomeStuffSpy = sinon.spy MyClass, 'doSomeStuff'
  $('#my-form').find('textarea').val('content')
  $('#my-form').submit()
  expect(doSomeStuffSpy).to.have.been.calledOnce
```

It appears that the submission never occurs, and my assertion is always false. Is there a way that I can test form submissions like this? I don't need to test POSTing anything. I just want to test that stuff that happens after the `onsubmit` callback is run.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

couple ideas. are you sure you are spying on the proper instance/prototype of the method?

in your test, shouldn't you be checking that the method on the instance is getting called, since it appears that is a method on the instance of the `MyClass` class.

```
doSomeStuffSpy = sinon.spy myClass, 'doSomeStuff'
```

in your submit handler, you are probably calling `@doSomeStuff()` on the event, not the class, since the event handler is not bound to the context of the class `=>`.

contextually, you might want to make sure that you are not binding these events to the global context `$('#my-form').on 'submit', (e) ->` and rather bind it to the instance of class itself (which makes it easier to spy and encapsulates the event to the dom fragment). Akin to Backbone Views.

```
class MyClass
  constructor: (el)->
    @$el = $(el)
    @$el.on 'submit', @doStuff

  doStuff: (e)=> # bound to the context of the class, not the event.
```

which should be testable, something like:

```
myClass = MyClass.new("<form></form")
spy = Sinon.createSpy myClass, 'doStuff'
myClass.trigger 'submit'
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

you can also check that dom updates happen from the callback by doing expectations like

```
value = myClass.$el.find('input').val()
expect(value).toEqual('foo')
```

which is less prone to failure than going from a global context and allows you to test you components in isolation from the actual dom you have in your app.